# Display a static block in Homepage listing all categories

Tags: magento2, category, static-block, cms-block

I'd like to display a static block in my CMS Homepage which lists all 1 level categories.

How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

For **Home Pag**e :

1. Go To Magento Admin -> Content -> Pages
2. Edit your current Hompage which you set for the website.
3. Now call your particular CMS Block using this code :

> {{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}

For **Category** :

1. Go To Magento Admin -> Catalog -> Categories.
2. Edit the Category into which you want to show that block.
3. Go To Display Setting section on right side.
4. Set `"Display Mode"` either to `"Static block only"` or `"Static block and products"` according to your requirement.
5. Set your CSM block into the `"Add CMS Block"` fields.

Now clear the cache and check the frontend.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but what I'd like to achieve is to list and display, with some PHP code, all the first level categories in the static block.

Comment: Then you can added the block by xml for all categories, and in phtml first check if this is first level category then show the block otherwise not.

Comment: I want to add the block to the homepage only, then, in that block, I'd like to list all first level categories using PHP.